# Setting precision and machine underflow

Tags: machine-precision

As is well known, Mathematica changed how it handles numbers smaller than $MinMachineNumber in recent versions.

I'm running Mathematica 12 on a Mac, and I cannot figure out why it's treating these differently:

```
   Exp[-N[2695, $MachinePrecision]]
   Exp[-N[2695.0, $MachinePrecision]]
```

The top line returns 3.77... times 10^-1171 while the bottom line gives the "too small to represent as a normalized machine number" error and returns zero.

Since both numbers are set to MachinePrecision I'd think that the fact that the bottom one has the added .0 is irrelevant, but obviously my understanding is wrong.

Running

```
    N[Precision[-N[2695, $MachinePrecision]]]
    N[Precision[-N[2695.0, $MachinePrecision]]]
```

confirms both exponents have the same precision.

I'd greatly appreciate it if someone could explain why Mathematica is treating these differently to me.

Comment: Removing the outer `N[...]` from both will show that they are in fact different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, that is somewhat odd. The reason is this:

```
Precision[N[2695, $MachinePrecision]]
Precision[N[2695.0, $MachinePrecision]]
```

> 15.9546
>
> MachinePrecision

In fact, one has to be careful with the subtle difference between the following two:

```
$MachinePrecision
MachinePrecision
```

> 15.9546
>
> MachinePrecision

That is, `N[2695, $MachinePrecision]` is actually *not* a machine number but an *arbitrary precision number* with as many digits as a machine number. Thus,  over- and underflows in numerical computations will be treated differently.

In the case of `N[2695.0, $MachinePrecision]`, one has to keep in mind that `N` can never increase the precision (one had to use `SetPrecision` for that). And `MachinePrecision` is always treated as smaller precision than any arbitrary precision. So, curiously one has `MachinePrecision < $MachinePrecision` and `N[2695.0, $MachinePrecision]` does not change `2695.0` from a machine number to an arbitrary precision number with `15.9546` digits.

In a nutshell:

`N[2695, $MachinePrecision]` is an arbitrary precision number because (i) `2695` is exact and (ii) `$MachinePrecision` evaluates to `15.9546`.

`N[2695.0, $MachinePrecision]` is a machine number because (i) `2695.0`is  a machine number,  because (ii) `$MachinePrecision` evaluates to `15.9546` which is treated by *Mathematica* as a *higher* precision than `MachinePrecision`, and because (iii) `N` cannot increase the `Precision` of its input.

Comment: That clarifies a lot, although I still don't understand why Mathematica isn't doing the same thing to both. Why is one an arbitrary precision number but not the other?

Comment: @LaurenPearce In the first case, you end up with an exact number being reduced to an arbitrary precision number with a precision of 15.9546. In the second case, you start out with a machine precision number. To switch it to an arbitrary precision number with precision of 15.9546 is considered by Mathematica to be more precision, and it does not want to increase the precision without an explicit command. You can also try `Precision[N[2695, MachinePrecision]]`. Using `$MachinePrecision` with the dollar sign is the same as typing `Precision[N[2695, 15.9546]]`.